# Using RcTooltip with react-minimal-pie-chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use rc- tooltip with react-minimal-pie-chart so it will be shown on hover of each of the pie chart parts with no luck.

I tried using it like this:

```
<ToolTip {...toolToolInfo}>
<PieChart
    data={info}
    startAngle={270}
    lineWidth={50}
    paddingAngle={2}
    background={backgroundColor}
    onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
    onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
    segmentsStyle={getSegmentStyle}
  />
</ToolTip>
```

This is example of what i want: [link](https://toomuchdesign.github.io/react-minimal-pie-chart/index.html?path=/story/misc--tooltip-integration)

Same as that but with rc tooltip.